# Findbugs does not work for web, Ejb

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

I use Eclipse Luna, JDK 7. I am new to [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and recently installed as [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Findbugs/article.html) explains. However, it works for simple projects such as libraries(this has only POJO s and functioning classes only). I have a web project (basically struts) and a ejb project. When I run FindBugs for both, it doesn't work but only it shows the processing and then it lost.
Has any one experienced this before  ? please let me how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using FindBugs on my web projects (Spring MVC) and had no such problem, the issue might be caused from the severity settings of the plug-in.

You should try lowering the minimum severity from

**Preferences -> Java -> FindBugs**